# If eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are positive, is the matrix positive definite?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

If eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are positive, does that mean it is positive definite? please give an example of why this is incorrect.

Comment: What are you using as the definition of "positive definite"?  Are you considering complex matrices that are symmetric but not hermitian?

Answer (score 1):

The symmetric (but not hermitian) matrix $$ \pmatrix{2 & i\cr i & 0\cr}$$ has $1$ as its only eigenvalue, but it is not positive definite.

Comment: can you also give an example with integer numbers and not complex?

Comment: No, because the statement is true for real symmetric matrices.